# Google Cloud Vision produce duplicate files in android studio

Tags: android, api, gradle

I'm using android studio and cloud vision in order to detect faces features in a picture. When compiling, I get this error (About cloud vision V 1.53):

```
Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/INDEX.LIST
    File1: /home/dragonklavier/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-core-grpc/1.53.0/f86ad24d0f605abab1bd8020f2ab357125be404d/google-cloud-core-grpc-1.53.0.jar
    File2: /home/dragonklavier/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-vision/1.53.0/e54a24754ed11d72bfd9f0b8d0d078dca3c7533f/google-cloud-vision-1.53.0.jar
    File3: /home/dragonklavier/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-core/1.53.0/3f87dfdae359ce1cdb738d4feac6569792f54ee9/google-cloud-core-1.53.0.jar
```

My Gradles dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'

   compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-vision:1.53.0'



   compile 'net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-distribution:3.4.3'

    //compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'


    compile('com.sangcomz:FishBun:0.6.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this too your gradle

```
android{
    compileSdkVersion sdk_version
    defaultConfig {
    //config
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
   }
}
```